# sort very large data with dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, dask

I need to sort a data table that is well over the size of the physical memory of the machine I am using. Pandas cannot handle it because it needs to read the entire data into memory. Can dask handle that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by calling `set_index` on the column that you wish to sort.  On a single machine it uses your hard drive intelligently for excess space.